# Are there any plans to integrate Web Apps to the Software Center?

Tags: software-center, 12.10, webapps

Web Apps can now [integrate](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/webapps) with Ubuntu.

It would be quite neat to add web apps to the software center. For example if someone searches for a chat application in the software center it would be nice to also offer web app chat clients.

Does the Ubuntu Team plan to do so?
If yes, in the near future?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that several web apps are now available to install directly from Ubuntu's repositories, using either `apt-get install` or the Ubuntu Software Center.

To install all currently available web apps, you can simply use the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-webapps-*
```

*([Source](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/unity-webapps-available-in-ubuntu-1210.html) for further reading.)*

Comment: Thanks. going to check this out now *O* 12.10 rocks already :D

Comment: last.fm works. costs money :( gmail did not work for me.

Comment: Actually, the "userscripts" for webapps is really just to support sites that haven't yet integrated directly from their site, see http://askubuntu.com/a/201733/17323