# How to add a Web App to Ubuntu's repositories?

Tags: software-center, webapps

According to [This Question](https://askubuntu.com/a/194499/17323), some webapps like gmail are now *"install-able"*.

I'm the developer of [Timer-Tab.com](http://www.timer-tab.com) and have already integrated it with the Unity Desktop using the [Unity Web API](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/ubuntu-12.04/javascript/index.html).

Are there any plans to allow web developers to add their app to the repositories so that one can do `apt-get install unity-webapps-timertab`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the "userscripts" for webapps is really just to support sites that haven't yet integrated directly from their site.

Website developers should ideally build the support into the site with javascript instead of using userscripts (like you have done).  This would enable the integration without even installing a package and eases maintenance as well as making it easier for users to just use the integration without having to install anything.

Comment: is there any ways I can add Timer Tab to the software-center? I.e. do you know anything about http://askubuntu.com/questions/194498/are-there-any-plans-to-integrate-web-apps-to-the-software-center ?

Answer (score 2):

Once you have built in the support for Ubuntu webapps with site JavaScript, and a user launches your site, Ubuntu will offer to install the site as a webapp. If that is chosen, an icon for the site will appear in the launcher, which can be locked in the launcher if desired (as for all other applications).

For example I launched timer-tab.com with Firefox (for some reason it didn't work right away with the Chrome browser when that was my default browser), I was offered a choice to install the timer-tab webapp. I said yes and locked it to my launcher. Now when I click its icon, Firefox launches timer-tab and the launcher icon displays the time remaining.

In other words, it isn't necessary to install a package nor add the web app to the Ubuntu repositories.